# What is a word for describing web experience which makes you feel you're interacting with a human, and not a robot. Personalized?

Tags: vocabulary

How do you describe web experience which makes you feel that you are interacting with a human, or humans are a part of the process, rather than a robot?

For example, you have two news-letter subscription forms. One is labelled:

```
-----NEWSLETTER SUBSCRIPTION FORM-----
--------------------------------------
---Email : _______________________ ---
--------------------------------------
-------SUBMIT-----------CANCEL--------
```

And another one is labelled:

```
-------------WANT THE LATEST IN WEB DESIGN------------
------------------------------------------------------
-------Just enter your email : _____________----------
------------------------------------------------------
-----Yes, please.----------I am OK being outdated-----
```

[(I picked it from here)](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/power-of-email-lists/)

You can see that the second results in much more personalized [1](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/power-of-email-lists/) user experience, and thus develops trust at a subconscious level and the user feels more welcomed.

The way I can describe it is that, well if I were the user, I would feel I was interacting with a bot/robot, whereas in second one, I feel that I am interacting with a human, that there is a human behind the process. A humanly connection is developed.

**But how do I describe this? The second one results in a more _______ user experience. Please fill in the blank.**

---

[1](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/power-of-email-lists/) *I have been thinking that the word 'personalized' will do, but just confirmed from the dictionary, and it means*

> Made for, directed or adjusted to a particular individual

*So it rather seems to mean that user experience adapts to the preferences of the individual experiencing/using it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the adjective **human** is a good choice:

> belonging to or relating to people, especially **as opposed to machines** or animals

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/human_1))

Examples:

> By giving the candidate direct access to the consultant online, via chat and social integration we create **a more human experience** - connecting online and real world experiences very closely.

([www.designbyclear.com](http://www.designbyclear.com/work/dylan-website-recruitment-web-design/))

> It’s one thing to make technology **more human**, with Siri-like apps that talk and listen.

([medium.com](https://medium.com/backchannel/why-are-tech-companies-telling-us-computers-will-make-us-more-human-a20484975e38#.yuy0rl4vq))

"Personalized" doesn't really work here, as the message is not tailored to the individual who views it. To be personalized, it could say something like "Hi *John*, would you like to get the latest in web design?"